# Python3.6 cannot catch KeyboardInterrupt When i use loop.run_forever() on win1

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, loops, python-asyncio, keyboardinterrupt

I want to make a `tcpserver` use `asyncio`. first I use:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
server = asyncio.start_server(process, host="0.0.0.0", port=8888, loop=loop)
loop.run_until_complete(Server)
```

But I found `loop.run_until_complete` will return immediately，so I call `loop.run_forever()` to block it. And then it cannot catch the `KeyboardInterrupt`.

```
import time, asyncio, socket, sys


async def process(self, reader, writer):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)


try:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    server = asyncio.start_server(process, host="0.0.0.0", port=8888, loop=Loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(server)
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
    loop.stop()
    loop.close()
```

This code work properly on linux(python3.6), but can't be stopped on win10 15063(python3.6).
Please help.